# What happens to offered bounty, after accepted answer was removed and another answer was accepted?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258934/what-does-active-means-in-following-jquery-code/25520719) sometime back, which was suppose to award a bounty. I answered the question and someone answered the question using the sources which I provided. That answer got accepted and offered the bounty.

Meanwhile I flagged that answer.

> This answer is a copy of my answer's one of the references. It has been copied without any acknowledgment. stackoverflow.com/questions/3148225/jquery-active-function

Couple of days later that answer was removed by a moderator, then my answer was accepted. My question is, now where is that offered bounty has gone? Is it with person who gave the first accepted answer or it it went to nowhere? And also I have a feeling that, bounty should be awarded to my answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I added the flag contents.

Comment: At 10K+ I can see the deleted post and the comments on that.

Comment: For what it's worth, the answer was accepted after the bounty was already auto awarded, so the author got half the points. (which were removed anyway when the answer was deleted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bounty is gone; it cannot be re-awarded.

When the other answer was unaccepted and deleted, the bounty disappeared with it (the owner of that answer lost the +25 reputation as well as the upvotes and accept). Moderators cannot re-award it to your answer either, sorry.